# Changing a row into a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, transpose

I have a query in mysql which returns the following:

```
Amount1    Amount2    Amount3    
    0.1        0.3        0.6
```

I need the data in the following format:

```
Amount1   0.1
Amount2   0.3
Amount3   0.6
```

The query always return a single row with three columns. How can I change the format?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Comment: Plz share your schema design.

Comment: That would be 'changing a column into a row' !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option is to select each column per query and union them all.

**Example**:

```
select 'Amount1' as amount_type, `Amount1` as amount_value from your_query_results
union all
select 'Amount2', `Amount2` from your_query_results
union all
select 'Amount3', `Amount3` from your_query_results
```